# Vagrant up fails with a locally available box

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-windows

DISCLAIMER: This question is NOT a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23183217/vagrant-cant-find-existing-box). The solution from that post (to use file:// protocol when adding the box) did not solve the issue for me.

I am new to Vagrant. Downloaded a custom box because I need to investigate something about this particular box. I can't get vagrant up to work. It fails because Vagrant tries to download a box I already installed from a local file.

Here's my console output:

```
[andymac@x58Manjaro Boxes]$ pwd
/home/andymac/Boxes

[andymac@x58Manjaro Boxes]$ ls -la
total 737884
drwxr-xr-x  2 andymac andymac      4096 Mar 25 10:21 .
drwxr-xr-x 41 andymac andymac      4096 Mar 25 10:15 ..
-rwxrwxrwx  1 andymac andymac 755579528 Mar 25 09:42 rhel-7.8-beta-1-mlnx-x86_64.2002.01.libvirt.box

[andymac@x58Manjaro Boxes]$ vagrant box add rhel-7.8-beta1 file:///home/andymac/Boxes/rhel-7.8-beta-1-mlnx-x86_64.2002.01.libvirt.box
==> box: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
==> box: Adding box 'rhel-7.8-beta1' (v0) for provider: 
    box: Unpacking necessary files from: file:///home/andymac/Boxes/rhel-7.8-beta-1-mlnx-x86_64.2002.01.libvirt.box
==> box: Successfully added box 'rhel-7.8-beta1' (v0) for 'libvirt'!

[andymac@x58Manjaro Boxes]$ vagrant box list
rhel-7.8-beta1 (libvirt, 0)

[andymac@x58Manjaro Boxes]$ vagrant init rhel-7.8-beta1
A `Vagrantfile` has been placed in this directory. You are now
ready to `vagrant up` your first virtual environment! Please read
the comments in the Vagrantfile as well as documentation on
`vagrantup.com` for more information on using Vagrant.

[andymac@x58Manjaro Boxes]$ ls -la
total 737888
drwxr-xr-x  2 andymac andymac      4096 Mar 25 10:24 .
drwxr-xr-x 41 andymac andymac      4096 Mar 25 10:15 ..
-rwxrwxrwx  1 andymac andymac 755579528 Mar 25 09:42 rhel-7.8-beta-1-mlnx-x86_64.2002.01.libvirt.box
-rw-r--r--  1 andymac andymac      3020 Mar 25 10:24 Vagrantfile

[andymac@x58Manjaro Boxes]$ vagrant box list
rhel-7.8-beta1 (libvirt, 0)

[andymac@x58Manjaro Boxes]$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'rhel-7.8-beta1' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
==> default: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
==> default: Adding box 'rhel-7.8-beta1' (v0) for provider: virtualbox
    default: Downloading: rhel-7.8-beta1
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

Couldn't open file /home/andymac/Boxes/rhel-7.8-beta1
```

OS for this output is Manjaro Linux (5.5.11-1-MANJARO), but I also run into same exact issue on Windows 10 1903 build 18362.720

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have installed a box for the **provider `libvirt`**:

> ```
> ==> box: Successfully added box 'rhel-7.8-beta1' (v0) for 'libvirt'!
>
> [andymac@x58Manjaro Boxes]$ vagrant box list
> rhel-7.8-beta1 (libvirt, 0)
> ```

And then you try to run it with the **default provider `virtualbox`**:

> ```
> Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
> ```

---

You need to run it with the **provider `libvirt`**, use this command:

```
vagrant up --provider=libvirt
```

Other way to set the provider is to set the environment variable:

```
export VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER=libvirt
```

Or to modify the `config.vm.provider` in your `Vagrantfile`.

See [vagrant-libvirt#start-vm](https://github.com/vagrant-libvirt/vagrant-libvirt/blob/master/README.md#start-vm) and [Basic Provider Usage #Default Provider](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/providers/basic_usage.html#default-provider)

---

Otherwise if you don't want to use `libvirt` but `virtualbox` you have to install a [`rhel` box for `virtualbox`](https://app.vagrantup.com/generic/boxes/rhel7)